# find numbers that end with a specific number(55) in array python

Tags: python, arrays, list

i have an array with random nums

```
a = [1, 123, 155, 200]
```

i need to find  that numbers that have at the end number 55
like
155, 255, 7055....

```
for i in a:
  some code
  ....
  some code
  
  print(len(array_of_55))
```

but i have this example that`s not optimized i think

```
def checkSuffix(A, B):
 
    # Convert numbers into strings
    s1 = str(A);
    s2 = str(B);
 
    # Find the lengths of strings
    # s1 and s2
    n1 = len(s1)
    n2 = len(s2)
 
    # Base Case
    if (n1 < n2):
        return False;
     
    # Traverse the strings s1 & s2
    for i in range(n2):
 
        # If at any index characters
        # are unequals then return false
        if (s1[n1 - i - 1] != s2[n2 - i - 1]):
            return False;
             
    # Return true
    return True;
     
# Driver Code
 
# Given numbers
A = 12345
B = 45;
 
# Function Call
result = checkSuffix(A, B);
 
# If B is a suffix of A, then
# print "Yes"
if (result):
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

how i can do it?
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Answer (score 5):

We can use a list comprehension along with the modulus.

```py
a = [1, 123, 155, 200]
output = [i for i in a if i % 100 == 55]
print(output)  # [155]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler logic. Numbers that end with 55 leave the remainder 55 on division with 100. So code:

```
a = [1, 123, 155, 200]
b = []
for i in a:
    if i%100==55:
        b.append(i)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way but it works:

```
a = [1, 123, 155, 200]
output = []
for num in a:
    num = str(num)
    if len(num) > 1:
        if num[-2:] == '55':
            output.append(int(num))
        else:
            pass
print(output)
```

**Output**

```
[155]
```

Comment: `num[-2] + num[-1]` could be written as `num[-2:]`. There's no need to split the data to two single character strings and add them together again if you can get everything you need at once.